# VC++ Variadic-Template-Template error C2244: unable to match function definition to an existing declaration

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012, variadic-templates, template-templates

this is probably a newb's error, i'm using Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler Nov 2012 CTP, and when i try to compile this:

```
#include <tuple>

class A
{
public:
    template <class... Fs, template <class...> class T>
    void foo(T<Fs...>);
};

template <class... Fs, template <class...> class T>
void A::foo(T<Fs...>)
{
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.foo(std::make_tuple(10,10));
}
```

I get the following error:

```
error C2244: 'A::foo' : unable to match function definition to an existing declaration
definition
'void A::foo(T<Fs...>)'
existing declarations
'void A::foo(T<Fs...>)'
```

If I inline the function it compiles and does what i want to do, but i would have to put the function in a header file

But following code compiles with no error:

```
#include <vector>

class A
{
public:
    template <class Fs, template <class> class T>
    void foo(T<Fs>);
};

template <class Fs, template <class> class T>
void A::foo(T<Fs>)
{
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.foo(std::vector<int>());
}
```

So the question is how can i achieve the same thing with variadic templates

**Edit:**

As suggested filed a bug report at Microsoft Connect with the [ID :771567](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/771567/c-variadic-template-template-fail-to-compile-vs2012-nov-2012-ctp)

Also the vector example was bad (it would give `<std::_Simple_types<int>,std::_Vector_val>`, but it does compile), but if you try it with a pair and the template arguments:

```
template <class F, class G, template <class,class> class T>
```

you will get `<F,G,std::pair>` which is what i meant

Comment: VC doesn't actually support variadic templates. They just emulate them. So it's no wonder that doesn't work. The latter example shouldn't actually work, `std::vector` has more than one template parameter.

Comment: @mfontanini not true. Read about CTP mentioned by the author.

Comment: @user1832244 Your code compiles fine in gcc 4.7.2 and clang so it is probably one of many bugs introduced with that VS CTP.

Comment: Well Nov CTP is not production quality compiler and hence the bug. BTW this code compiles fine on GCC4.8

Comment: @MateuszPusz holly bjarnes, they finally implemented it.

Comment: @Sarang C++11 *is* C++. Please don't remove the tag from those questions. And dear edit peer reviewers, *please don't stop thinking*.

Comment: @mfontanini it [isn't really that hard to keep uptodate](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/) - so next time you put a compiler down, you know what the hell you talk about :) Variadics were ***never*** emulated to the extent that you could _use the syntax_. The effect was emulated w.r.t. overload sets in the standard library.

Comment: This is a bug.  Please open a bug report on [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio/), or, if you'd prefer not to, let me know and I can file a bug.  Thanks for trying out the CTP!

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: Is this really a compiler bug or simply related to the way variadics are emulated in the current stdlib implementation?

Comment: @MFH you don't need the stdlib to reproduce this bug, if you remove the function call from main, it will still fail to compile

Answer (score 0):

[From MSDN regarding Compiler Error C2244](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf190ysd.aspx):

> You cannot partially specialize a function template.

I also think you have to declare the `template` in front of the class:

```
template<typename T>
class MyClass
{
};
```